Installing WireGuard on Nvidia Tegra boards?
I am working with Nvidia Tegra SBCs for a custom application. The application uses the Nvidia GPU that is specific to these boards. The system is running aarch64 (arm64) Unubtu 22.04 Linux.
I need to use WireGuard on these. But I can't seem to get WireGuard to work with the Tegra kernel. I even tried wireguard-dkms. I would really prefer to use kernel mode because of the performance.
Linux 00000273 5.15.122-tegra #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Nov 30 10:30:37 PST 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

I read lots of people were having problems with this. Has anyone got a solution?

I was very sad to find this question with no answers when I started working on this problem myself. It was a doozy. I now have it working, so I'll share here to help others and my future self when I inevitably have this same problem again in a few months.
I first brought my kernel up to the current head with sudo do-release-upgrade until I was at 5.10.65-tegra. I then installed wireguard and wireguard-tools with sudo apt install  wireguard-tools wireguard. I suspect wireguard-tools was not needed but I'm not willing to uninstall it to check now that I have things working. At this point, checking the kernel module was still erroring for me:
>> sudo modprobe wireguard
modprobe: FATAL: Module wireguard not found in directory /lib/modules/5.10.65-tegra

I cloned the wireguard-linux-compat repository. If you just try to build this with running make after cding into wireguard-linux-compat/src you'll get the unhelpful error:
WireGuard has been merged into Linux >= 5.6 and therefore this compatibility module is no longer required.

because the 5.10.65-tegra kernel is after mainline Linux 5.6 but has the Wireguard module disabled.
The great thing about compiler directives is that they can be commented out. I found the offending error with grep and it was in wireguard-linux-compat/src/compat/compat.h and then just commented out the following:
/* 
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(5, 6, 0)
#error "WireGuard has been merged into Linux >= 5.6 and therefore this compatibility module is no longer required."
#endif
*/

From there, I could run make and then sudo make install and successfully install the kernel module. After this, sudo modprobe wireguard returned without output or error and I was able to go ahead and bring up my wireguard interface successfully.
I tried enough things getting this working that I won't claim that this will necessarily work without modification for you, but it did work for me and hopefully helps the next person who comes upon this problem.

Not enough reputation to comment on SleepyOtter's answer, but here's a forked and updated version of wireguard-linux-compat for any poor souls who find that the original repo doesn't build for them. A few extra changes on top of SleepyOtter's answer for Linux 5.10.216-tegra.
https://github.com/dustin-richards-was-here/wireguard-linux-compat

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review

Please read the promotion policy - any affiliation with a link you post must be explicitly disclosed.
